# How to call a method for all non-null variables

Tags: c++, lambda

Given the following code:

```
class A {
    void DoStuff1(int x);
    void DoStuff2(float y);
    void DoStuff3(int a, float b);

    void DoStuff4(int c);
    void DoStuff4(float c);

    void ForEachChild(auto method);

    A* children[4];
}
```

So that within other methods I can call:

- `ForEachChild(DoStuff1(10));`
- `ForEachChild(DoStuff2(5.0f));`
- `ForEachChild(DoStuff3(15, 12.0f));`
- `DoStuff4(...)` overloading would be nice also, but not strictly needed

Or alternatively, if possible:

- `ForEachChild()->DoStuff1(10);`
- etc

`ForEachChild()` will iterate thru the `children` list and for each non-null pointer will call the method it was asked to call, with the variables that it simply forwards onward.

I have to do many things for all of the children and I'd rather not add a loop in all of those places, and I'd like to keep the code as readable as possible.

edit. Added the stuff about `DoStuff3()`, to make it clear that the methods number of parameters isn't fixed. And `DoStuff4()`.

Comment: What you want is *variadic templates* and *argument forwarding*. There are many example on how to use that if you just search a little using the correct terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a *member-function template*.

```
class A {
    void DoStuff1(int x);
    void DoStuff2(float y);

    template<typename... T, typename... U>
    void ForEachChild(void (A::*method)(T...), U&&... x){
         for(auto child : children)
            if(child) (child->*method)(std::forward<U>(x)...);
    }
    A* children[4];
}
```

And use as:

```
object.ForEachChild(&A::DoStuff1, 10);
object.ForEachChild(&A::DoStuff2, 3.1416);
object.ForEachChild(&A::DoStuff3, 3, 546.353);

object.ForEachChild(static_cast<void(A::*)(int)>(&A::DoStuff4), 3);
object.ForEachChild(static_cast<void(A::*)(float)>(&A::DoStuff4), 3);
```

Note that you require a cast to pass the the [address of an *overloaded function*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address)...

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcebd2504fabc280)

Comment: @Holt, In addition to Jarod's comment I did that in order to let [ICS](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics) kick in within the context of the member-function ptr call. If I used the same parameter types, I wouldn't get ICS kicking in... For example, my code above can make a valid call like `ForEachChild(&A::DoStuff2, 3.1416);` (note that `A::DoStuff2` takes a `float` while we passed it a literal of `double`-type), while your suggestion [will fail](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e41af3f27ea6a337)

Comment: Yes and you cannot use a const-reference or reference because in the first case you would not be able to bind to non-const reference and in the second you would not be able to bind to temporaries. As Jarod pointed out, you should not forward here actually.

Comment: @WhiZTiM I added `DoStuff3(int a, float b)` to the question, your solution doesn't seem to work with it?

Comment: @user3358771, I've updated my answer, to reflect the update to your question and comment, and updated the [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcebd2504fabc280)